# How to compare two list of different sizes in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a `ListA` with `objectA`.

`objectA` has name, age, rollno, rank

and other `ListB` with `objectB`.

`objectB` has name,age

How can I compare two list and filter out uncommon records on the basis of name and age.

Comment: Look into [`IComparer`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727)

Comment: Please work out what kind of comparison you want. Comparison can be done in too many ways. i.e. when are those records considered equal? you want those records that have equal name and age in both lists as your result, right?

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample of classes:

```csh
public interface IHaveNameAndAge
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectA : IHaveNameAndAge
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    int RollNo { get; set; }
    int Rank { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB : IHaveNameAndAge
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<IHaveNameAndAge>
{
    public bool Equals(IHaveNameAndAge x, IHaveNameAndAge y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true; 
        return x.Age == y.Age && String.Equals(x.Name, y.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IHaveNameAndAge obj)
    {
        return obj.Age.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Here is test code:

```csh
var listA = new List<ObjectA>();
listA.Add(new ObjectA() { Name = "A", Age = 20 });
listA.Add(new ObjectA() { Name = "B", Age = 25 });
var listB = new List<ObjectB>();
listB.Add(new ObjectB() { Name = "A", Age = 20 });
listB.Add(new ObjectB() { Name = "C", Age = 29 });

var myComparer = new MyEqualityComparer();
var result = listA.Intersect<IHaveNameAndAge>(listB, myComparer);
```

You can modify this example in accordance with your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little trick for comparing different types that don't have a common base type. Create an `IEqualityComparer<object>` such as :

```
public class DynamicComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
{
    public bool Equals(dynamic x, dynamic y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name && x.Age == y.Age;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(dynamic obj)
    {
        return ((string)obj.Name).GetHashCode() * 31
            + ((int)obj.Age).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var filtered = ListA.Intersect(ListB, new DynamicComparer())
                    .Cast<objectA>().ToList();
```

---

**How it works.** Since `object` is a common base type for all types, the `IEqualityComparer<object>` works fine for different types. However, we normally wouldn't be able to compare the `Name` and `Age` properties since those aren't defined in `object`. The trick here is that the compiler allows you to put `dynamic` in place of `object` in the `IEqualityComparer<object>` method signatures and those still fulfill the contract. Therefore, we get to utilize the dynamic runtime to compare the properties common to both `objectA` and `objectB` types.

Comment: if you are relying on a property to be there, there really is no advantage of using dynamic - just define an interface and use a strongly typed comparer

Comment: @BrokenGlass the previous answer requires that the two types have a common base class. This answer uses dynamic so that you can compare two types _without_ the requirement to have a common base class. The advantage of dynamic is that you can just assume the properties exists without relying on inheritence or interfaces (i.e "duck typing").

Comment: I'm aware of that - I would just never do this in production code - having both classes implement a common interface is a much superior solution in my opinion

Comment: agreed, except to the point of "never". There may be cases where you can't or don't want to add an interface -- e.g. some 3rd party sealed class or a shared library. This is just an option.